# How to apply string styles to HtmlElement?

Tags: javascript

I have tried this way to join all styles in string:

```
pointElement.style = `
    display: 'block',
    left: ${(rotated_x + w / 2) / scale}px,
    top: ${(h / 2 - rotated_y) / scale}px`;
```

It is not applied.

Comment: `.style` is an object, not a string. Just apply each one individually. Or merge your two objects.

Comment: Could you post answer how to mrge in object?

Comment: `.style.cssText = "..."`

Comment: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171251)

Comment: There is few answers: `element.style.left = "20px"` or  div.style.cssText=`color: red !important;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  `;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this,

```
pointElement.style.display = 'block';
pointElement.style.left = `${(rotated_x + w / 2) / scale}px`;
pointElement.style.top = `${(h / 2 - rotated_y) / scale}px`;
```

But don't forget to use `position: absolute;` CSS property to apply your left and top properties. You will also need to have a container element which has `position: relative;` CSS property for absolute positioning of your inner pointElement.